# dynamic dropdown list ( select boxes )

Tags: javascript, forms

Here is the issue.

I have a select dropdown list.

```
   <select name="listingtype" id="speedD" style="width:210px;">
      <option>For Sale</option>
      <option>For Rent</option>
   </select>
```

And another select drop down list where the prices appear , which on page load it is empty..

So if user clicks For Sale: then the other select drop down list, loads price list like so:

```
   <select name="valueA" id="speedF" style="width:200px;">
     <option value="Any" selected="selected">Any</option>
     <option value="50000">$50,000</option>
     <option value="100000">$100,000</option>
     <option value="150000">$150,000</option>
     <option value="200000">$200,000</option>
     <option value="250000">$250,000</option>
```

And if they choose For Rent. Select drop down is propagated like so:

```
<select name="valueA" id="speedF" style="width:200px;">
    <option value="Any" selected="selected">Any</option>
    <option value="100">$100</option>
    <option value="150">$150</option>
    <option value="200">$200</option>
    <option value="250">$250</option>
    <option value="300">$300</option>
</select>
```

I need this code to be client side, no need for server side. And just wanted to know what the cleanest method for doing this is.

Cheers.

Comment: We'll help with problems, but not with coding it for you.

Comment: Well for some reason, the link I posted in the question wasnt included. But thanks for your valued input. Will amend the question

Comment: Can you opt for jQuery for this instance?

Comment: Yes looks like jQuery is the go huh

Comment: So which is it, all client side or do you want to use AJAX (noting that AJAX requires a trip to the server)?

Comment: Apologies, as per original question: "And just wanted to know what the cleanest method for doing this is." I prefer not to be ajax. We use jquery UI. Setting the form values via an array and calling them on event change seems to be the go. The issue, really I suppose is there is quite a lot of data to be imported, which is where I was kinda getting stuck.. looking for the cleanest method. Each select drop down, has a minimum and maximum price range, and there is for sale and for rent, so lots of values, arrays being the cleanest method.

Answer (score 2):

First of all I recommend setting the value attribute in your option elements.
Example:

```
<option value="sale">For sale</option>
<option value="rent">For rent</option>
```

If you have not already heard of or seen the JavaScript library known as jQuery I strongly recommend checking it out! It can be very helpful when creating a dynamic site like this using minimal JavaScript.

I would do something like the following:

```
<html>
...
<body>
<div id="fillme"></div>
<script type="text/javascript">
    if (document.yourformname.listingtype.value == "sale") {
        //it is for sale
        $('#fillme').html('<select name="valueA" id="speedF" style="width:200px;"><option value="Any" selected="selected">Any</option><option value="50000">$50,000</option><option value="100000">$100,000</option><option value="150000">$150,000</option><option value="200000">$200,000</option><option value="250000">$250,000</option></select>');
    } else {
        //fill it with the other elements
    }
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

Now of course you could load it more dynamically with JSON or XML but that is up to you. I really recommend checking out the library:
http://jQuery.com

Comment: ahh , okies thats a cool idea. Will have a play with that  thanks

Comment: also another good resource for making your page look pretty and making your form elements look good you can go to www.jqueryui.com that will be useful once you get the hand of jquery

Comment: our forms are prettier than dolly parton on speed ;) In fact the elements use jquery ui.

Answer (score 1):

Use JavaScript to fill the empty select with options when the user selects an option (either `onchange` or `onselect`, forget which) in the For Sale/For Rent select.

EDIT: More specifically, have that second box be empty when the page loads. Store the options in arrays. Use a loop to create new OPTION elements based on each array item.

Comment: Thanks David, exactly what I was thinking re the arrays.Thanks